# Infinite matrix of non negative numbers (sequence)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, matrices, infinite-matrices

Suppose that we have matrix $\begin{Bmatrix}a_{ij}\end{Bmatrix}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of non negative real numbers. Let $\pi : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ be bijection so $\begin{Bmatrix}a_{\pi _{1}(n)\pi _{2}(n)}\end{Bmatrix}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a rearrangement of the matrix.
     Prove that 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{ \pi _{1}(n)\pi _{2}(n)}$$ and $$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}(\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_{ij})$$
are both convergent (and their sums are equal) or both divergent. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Posted also on MO: [Infinite matrix of non negative numbers (sequence)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270959). I find the advice given in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) a very reasonable. Of course, you might have a look at other discussions regarding ([meta-tag:cross-posting]), too.

Comment: Now when I looked more closely at the two posts, this one contains $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \pi _{1}(n)\pi _{2}(n)$ and the other one contains $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{\pi _{1}(n)\pi _{2}(n)}$. Which of the two is it supposed to be?

Comment: It is the second one. I have just edited the question. Thanks!